# Commit changes is disabled even after I change the content in the file?

Tags: github

[image]

I'm new to using GitHub,
Commit changes is disabled when I try to edit the content in the file and save. What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you provide a commit message? Is this your repository? Is committing directly to main allowed?

Comment: I am not sure if I have provided a commit message, when I directly drag or drop files is there a need for commit message.Yes, it is my repo. I am not sure if it is allowed.

Comment: I tried opening github in Chrome and there was no issue, I'm facing this issue in Firefox.

Comment: My 2 cents: I know this sort of thing is possible, and perhaps useful for a quick and dirty file addition, but you are reducing github to the equivalent of scp.  You should edit things in a local clone of your repo, and use either a tool or command line git to make changes to your repo.

Comment: I agree. My knowledge of command line is limited and when I am stuck this seems easy

Comment: Same problem with Firefox 102.0b5 and Github Web. My own repo with full access but I still can't commit changes even with the commit message filled in.


The same problem doesn't happen in Chrome AND Brave. Even without the commit message.

Comment: I flushed ALL cookies from my firefox and logged in again but still the Commit Changes button is disabled. Also the "Preview" button on markdown previews is non-functional on Firefox.

Comment: Found the erring extension: Ghostery. It was blocking the Adobe Experience Cloud tracker (??). Removed the extension completely.

Both MarkDown preview and Commit changes buttons work now. Yes!! :)